# Delete multiple records from different tables with SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a SQL agent job that executes a stored procedure every 5 minutes or so, but I'm at a loss with part of the SQL syntax. I'm using forms authentication and I need to select all users that have not been active in the last 15 minutes and have also been marked temporary. To do that, I will be grabbing `LastActivityDate` from table `aspnet_Users` and `IsTemp` from table `UserProfile`. After selection, I need to delete all traces of this user from my data. Below is the basic structure of my tables necessary for my question:

```
    aspnet_Users(uniqueidentifier UserId PK)
    aspnet_Membership(uniqueidentifier UserId FK)
    UserProfile(int UserProfileID PK, uniqueidentifier aspnetUserID FK, int IsTemp)
    UserFriend(int UserFriendID PK, int UserProfileID FK)
    Image(int ImageID PK, int UserProfileID FK)
    Message(int MessageID, int UserProfileID FK)
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CleanUpUserProfiles] 
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT *
        FROM [UserProfile]
        WHERE IsTemp = 1

        SELECT *
        FROM [aspnet_Users]
        WHERE LastActivityDate < DATEADD(mi, -15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

        SELECT *
        FROM [UserProfile]
        WHERE IsTemp = 1

        DELETE FROM [Message]
        WHERE ??? = @???

        DELETE FROM [Image]

        DELETE FROM [UserFriend]

        DELETE FROM [UserProfile]

        DELETE FROM [aspnet_Membership]

        DELETE FROM [aspnet_Users]

    END
    GO
```

I know I need a variable to hold the selected users from `aspnet_Users` in order to know which to delete, but I've no idea how to do that. Secondly, I only need to select users with `IsTemp = 1` from `UserProfile`. How would I include that in my select statement? I also understand that I'll need two `SELECT` statments. One to select `UserID` for use in deletion of `UserProfile`, `UserFriend`, `Image`, and `Message`, and another for selection of the `uniqueidentifier` I'll be using in `aspnet_Users` and `aspnet_Membership`. Please keep in mind I've not dealt with SQL much beyond basic stored procedure creation. Any help is very much appreciated.

If anybody's curious as to why I want to do this... I'm allowing users the option to remain anonymous by creating only a username upon entry to my service. These users will be temporary, and if somebody comes along and wants to use the same username days later, I don't want to prohibit them from doing so. I also don't want to hang on to unnecessary data, feels dirty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.. First fetch the `UserID's` that you have to delete and store them in a `Temp` table.

```
Select a.UserID into #UserToDelete from aspnet_users a
inner join UserProfile b on a.UserID = b.aspnetUserID
where IsTemp=1 and LastActivityDate < DATEADD(mi, -15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Now delete all these users from all your transaction tables.

```
DELETE FROM [Message] where UserProfileID in (select userid from #UserToDelete)
DELETE FROM [Image] where UserProfileID in (select userid from #UserToDelete)   
DELETE FROM [UserFriend] where UserProfileID in (select userid from #UserToDelete)  
DELETE FROM [UserProfile] where aspnetUserID in (select userid from #UserToDelete)
DELETE FROM [aspnet_Membership] where userID in (select userid from #UserToDelete)
DELETE FROM [aspnet_Users] where userID in (select userid from #UserToDelete)
```

Comment: Had to make a slight alteration as SSMS was giving an error for incorrect data type between `uniqueidentifier` and `int`. Ended up doing a separate `SELECT` statement as follows: `SELECT a.UserID into #UserProfilesToDelete FROM [UserProfile] a
 INNER JOIN [aspnet_Users] b on a.aspUserID = b.UserId
 WHERE [Type] = 1 AND LastActivityDate < DATEADD(MI, -15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);` and used it to delete by `UserProfileID`. But you put me on the right track, thanks.

Comment: @TestWell .. Thanks if you have anything else then post as new question. If it helped then upvote please.